# Sql Server Services not restarting - The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I tried to establish remote connection to my Sql Server 2014 on Windows Server 2008 machine. To do this I enabled TCP/IP added port 1433. The prompt asked me to restart my services for the changes to take effect. However on trying to restart the services, I'm getting the below error message -

> The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details.

The steps I have tried - 
1. Tried disabling VIA
2. Tried replacing Master and MastLog files from TemplateData to Data
3. Tried disabling TCP/IP
4. Tried starting the services with user as local system

I tried the above based on similar questions from stackoverflow and nothing seems to work.

[image: MSSQLSERVER2014 is the server i need]

Comment: Is there anything in the SQL Server log directory? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187885%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details: what does it says? And ERROR log ? (file location: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/03/24/sql-server-where-is-errorlog-various-ways-to-find-its-location/)